Ghost bottom tabs nav button when Iconify is used and bottom tabs are hidden on AVD
Using an AVD (Pixel 5) running API 34, if I use Iconify icons for my bottom tab, on screens where the bottom tab is hidden, clicking the top left corner of the screen can register a click on the last (right-most) tab button (page 3 in my example).
Additionally, if another tab in the bar has an Iconify icon with increased size (page 2 in my example), it can also be triggered by clicking somewhere in the top left corner of the screen.
I can verify this does not happen on my iOS device, and I have seen similar behaviour on physical android devices in production.
Reproducible example: https://github.com/nathantew14/ghost-btm-tab-nav-btn
I did post this as an issue on react-navigation's github last year but there has been zero activity. You can watch a video of my problem there: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/11691
I'm coming back and posting this because this problem is back to haunt me in a different form, this time the "ghost button" is smack dab in the middle of the screen in one horizontal bar across the screen where tapping it brings me to another screen when it shouldn't. I can also confirm that this issue is happening to my app's users in production.

Using debug tools->inspector shows that the SVG were drawn but not visible, even when the tabBarStyle is set to display: "none".
Workaround: Wrap Iconify with <View style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}>
import "expo-dev-client";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { Iconify } from "react-native-iconify";
import Page1 from "./Page1";
import Page2 from "./Page2";
import Page3 from "./Page3";
import { View } from "react-native";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        // must render a page with the tabBar visibile at least once for "ghost button" to appear
        initialRouteName="3"
        // it does not matter if header is shown, but i'm hiding it so I can
        // display the "click here" positions accurately
        screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name="1"
          component={Page1}
          // tabBarStyle display must be "none" for "ghost button" to appear on this screen
          options={{ tabBarStyle: { display: "none" } }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="2"
          component={Page2}
          options={{
            // tabBarStyle display must be "none" for "ghost button" to appear on this screen
            tabBarStyle: { display: "none" },
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <View style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}>
                <Iconify //iconify is necessary for "ghost button" to page 2
                  color={color}
                  // size={size}
                  size={size + 15} //larger size is necessary for "ghost button" to page 2
                  icon="material-symbols:circle-outline"
                />
              </View>
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen //the ghost button for page 3 only works if it is the last tab
          name="3"
          component={Page3}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              //iconify is necessary for "ghost button" to page 3
              <View style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}>
                <Iconify color={color} size={size} icon="gg:profile" />
              </View>
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}


This seems to be an issue caused by SvgXml as Ionicons work as expected.
But finally I don`t know who is the culprit here SvgXml or react-navigation ...
I guess iOS and android behave same here but the pressable areas were hidden behind the status bar.

I did post this as an issue on react-navigation's github last year but there has been zero activity. You can watch a video of my problem there: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/11691

Your question were not clear, I took me some time to understand what's the issue here, that is probably the reason no one respond.

Oh wow, you did it. Can't believe this incomprehensible bug has been solved. Although, I really still don't get why it happens. Why only when display is set to none? Why did the svg float all the way to the corner of the screen?
Regarding my github issue, you really think it's not clear? I really thought I made it as explicit and clear as possible, complete with a video demo and a reproducible example. How would you recommend I improve it?
Thanks.
